# Get field value before update

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get value before and update query in update query itself?

For example:

```
UPDATE t SET field1 = 'new', field2 = IF (field2 = field1, 'new', field2))
```

In 'field2 = field1' I want to check the previous value of field. Mysql works in a such way that it updates field1 and then will make comparison with the new value, so the comparison  always will be "IF (field2 = 'new', ..."

So I would like something like

```
UPDATE t SET field1 = 'new', field2 = IF (field2 = PREVIOUS_VALUE(field1), 'new', field2))
```

Updated:

swapping may not work sometimes in more complex examples, when I want it like this:

```
UPDATE t SET field1 = IF (field1 = PREVIOUS_VALUE(field2), 'new', field1)), field2 = IF (field2 = PREVIOUS_VALUE(field1), 'new', field2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just rearrange those sets.

```
UPDATE t
SET 
field2 = IF (field2 = field1, 'new', field2),
field1 = 'new';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb265/1

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the reverse order :

```
UPDATE t SET field2 = IF (field2 = field1, 'new', field2), field1 = 'new'
```